# mpg123 без вывода информации

Tags: linux

Как заставить mpg123 не выводить информацию о музыкальной композиции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как и у многих других программ, у этой программы есть опция `-q`:

```
$ mpg123 -q ...
```

---

из `man mpg123`:

```
-q, --quiet
       Quiet.  Suppress diagnostic messages.
```